# Selenium inconsistencies with clicking Yahoo UI button

Tags: selenium-rc, selenium-ide

I am using **Selenium IDE 1.8.1**  on **Firefox 12**. One of our applications uses **"Yahoo UI"** based buttons and I keep seeing inconsistent results with Selenium when trying to click them. For example, clicking this button **(input id="submitButton")** should pop up a modal dialog--and about half the time it submits the data but the modal dialog never pops up.
I am using the command:  `click | css=#submitButton |`

```
<input id="icdParticipantAddressForm_icdParticipantId" type="hidden" value="1022" name="icdParticipantId">
<input id="submitButton" class="saveButtonImage" type="submit" onclick="return YAHOO.ourAddress.avwController.verifyAddresses();" title="save" value="Next" style="float:right;">
<a href="/url?icdParticipantId=1022>
```

Thanks all!
P.S. I've also tried
`fireEvent | css=#submitButton | click` with the same results

Answer (score 0):

If you couldn't access it at all; I'll assume that it was hidden (behind a frame?). The fact that you experience 'inconsistency' each time you run your tests leads me to believe that you have timeout issues. It will be useful to see what sort of error message you are getting.

Best way to get the button you desire is via XPATH; copy paste the code below to the portion of your code trying to locate the button.

```
driver.find_element(:xpath, "//input[@id='submitButton']")
```

Run your tests again and see if this is any help. If not try the improved code below which will cover you in case the page takes time to load (i.e. your button is not available yet).

```
!30.times { if (driver.find_element(:xpath, "//input[@id='submitButton']") rescue false) then break else sleep 1; end }
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is no "error, nor timeout issues"--it just goes to the next step in the test. Also, why would using Xpath help? It's just a location strategy. I've tried CSS already.